# Como imprimir un recibo de n valores introducidos con el ciclo for en C#?

Tags: c#

Este programa es básicamente un recibo en el cual quiero mostrar los productos comprados así como sus respectivos precios ademas de esto al final del recibo quiero desplegar el subtotal y el total de la compra(contando todos los productos) la cual debe incluir el 15% de tax,le he dado muchas vueltas pero no logro desplegar todos los datos que introduzco dentro del ciclo for y tampoco he realizado la suma total por el hecho de que no he resuelto lo antes mencionado.

Este es el código que llevo:

```
using System;

namespace RECIBO
{
    class Program
    {
        static int productos;
        static string nombreproducto;
        static int precio;
        static int resultado;
        static int i;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No de PRODUCTOS: ");
            productos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (i = 1; i <= productos; i++)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("PRODUCTO: ");
                    nombreproducto = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("PRECIO DE PRODUCTO: ");
                    precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }


            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("RECIBO");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("PRODUCTOS COMPRADOS: " + nombreproducto);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("SUBTOTAL: " + precio);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            metodo(resultado);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("GRACIAS POR SU VISITA");

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static void metodo(float tax)
        {

            tax = (precio * 0.15f);
            tax = precio + tax;
            Console.WriteLine("TOTAL: " + tax);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que defines varies `static` por lo tanto en cada iteracion del `for` pisas el dato anterior

Para solicitar varios datos debes tener una lista, puede ser un `List<>` o un array, recomiendo la lista

A nivel del namespace define una entidad con una class como ser:

```
public class Producto
{
    public string nombreproducto {get;set;}
    public int precio {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces despues usas esta para obtener la lista de productos

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Producto> Productos = new List<Producto>();

        Console.WriteLine("No de PRODUCTOS: ");
        int NroProductos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < NroProductos; i++)
        {
            Producto p = new Producto();

            Console.WriteLine("PRODUCTO: ");
            p.nombreproducto = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("PRECIO DE PRODUCTO: ");
            p.precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Productos.Add(p);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("RECIBO");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach(var p in Productos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRODUCTO COMPRADOS: {0}", p.nombreproducto);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        int suma = Suma(Productos);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("SUBTOTAL: {0}", suma);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        float total = Total(suma);
        Console.WriteLine("TOTAL: {0:N2}", total);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("GRACIAS POR SU VISITA");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static float Total(int suma)
    {
        float tax = (suma * 0.15f);
        return suma + tax;
    }

    static int Suma(List<Producto> lista)
    {
        int result = 0;
        foreach(var p in lista)
        {
            result += p.precio;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

La verdad no lo compile, puede que tenga algun detalle, pero creo que la idea se entiende

Veras que uso un `List<Producto>` para llevar los datos que se van cargando y luego se listan los nombre y se realiza la suma iterando esa lista

Trata de no romper las resposabilidades de los metodos, si vas a calcular un total que haga solo eso, que no muestre ademas el dato por consola, puede devolverlo y que alquien mas se encarga de mostrarlo si se necesita

Al pedir cada producto se crea una instancia del mismo

```
Producto p = new Producto();
```

y al final se agrega a la lista

```
Productos.Add(p);
```

para entender esas lineas necesita conocer `POO`

[Programación orientada a objetos (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming)

Nota: para usar el `List<>` seguramente debas definir el

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```